# An easy PC application maker for data logging application

Tags: c#, c++, .net, frameworks, ide

I am an embedded system designer and I want to make a Data logging applications on PC to go with my Measuring Instruments.
So I need to know which IDE or frame work or PC application maker? is better suited for me.

I know this may not be proper question for this site, but I looked everywhere I could for suggestion but I didn't get any Idea.

My requirement is to make an application which allows to read data from Serial Port and do some manipulation on Ascii string coming from Serial port, get date and time from PC and store it in excel file or as .txt, also it should provide good looking GUI.
I know only Embedded C, so it should be easy to learn since I am not from CS background.
Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I also came from an embedded C background and slowly transitioning to desktop applications, including data loggers. The easiest way for me to make applications is by using Visual Studio 2015, an SDK available for a certain device, and open source libraries (like OpenCV and boost). It was my first time dealing with classes, etc. but for me, it's easy to figure out. But you can make applications with GUI on Visual Studio 2015, just familiarize yourself in using it.

Comment: My experience with one visual studio based application showed that apps made in it are sluggish and slow.

Comment: Also is it free to make app and make exe file.?

Comment: Applications made with Visual Studio are basically free, I've already made several proprietary applications from it which run on Windows 10 64-bit. If you're going to use open source libraries in commercial software, you have to provide the source code to potential users as part of the Open Source Initiative (https://opensource.org/faq#commercial). As for the speed, it depends on how you code it. Some functionalities take too much processing power over others for the same result.